# Join two DataFrames on common columns only if the difference in a separate column is within range [-n, +n]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2` as shown below:

```
df1

Date        BillNo.     Amount
10/08/2020  ABBCSQ1ZA   878
10/09/2020  AADC9C1Z5   11
10/12/2020  AC928Q1ZS   3998
10/14/2020  AC9268RE3   198
10/16/2020  AA171E1Z0   5490
10/19/2020  BU073C1ZW   3432

df2

Date        BillNo.     Amount
10/08/2020  ABBCSQ1ZA   876
10/11/2020  ATRC95REW   115
10/14/2020  AC9268RE3   212
10/16/2020  AA171E1Z0   5491
10/25/2020  BPO66W2LO   344
```

My final answer should be:

```
final

Date        BillNo.     Amount
10/08/2020  ABBCSQ1ZA   876
10/16/2020  AA171E1Z0   5491
```

How do I find common rows from both the data frame using `Date BillNo. Amount` when the difference in value range is between [-5,5]?

I know how to find common rows by using:

```
df_all = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on=['Date', 'BillNo.', 'Amount'], 
                   how='outer', indicator=True)
```

However, this doesn't give the rows which are in range. Anyone who could help?

Edit: We can see in `df1: 10/14/2020,AC9268RE3,198` and `df2: 10/14/2020,AC9268RE3,212` the difference is 14, hence this should not be included in common rows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can merge, then perform a query to drop rows not within the range:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on=['Date', 'BillNo.'])
    .query('abs(Amount_x - Amount_y) <= 5')
    .drop('Amount_x', axis=1))

         Date    BillNo.  Amount_y
0  10/08/2020  ABBCSQ1ZA       876
1  10/16/2020  AA171E1Z0      5491
```

This works well as long as there is only one row that corresponds to a specific (Date, BillNo) combination in each frame.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
udf2 = df2.drop_duplicates().sort_values('Amount')
res = pd.merge_asof(udf2, df1.sort_values('Amount').assign(indicator=1), on='Amount', by=['Date', 'BillNo.'],
                    direction='nearest', tolerance=5)
res = res.dropna().drop('indicator', 1)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
         Date    BillNo.  Amount
2  10/08/2020  ABBCSQ1ZA     876
3  10/16/2020  AA171E1Z0    5491
```

Answer (score 2):

We can set `Date` and `BillNo.` as index as subtract both the dataframe and filter out only values b/w -5 to 5.

```
d1 = df1.set_index(['Date', 'BillNo.'])
d2 = df2.set_index(['Date', 'BillNo.'])

idx = (d1-d2).query('Amount>=-5 & Amount<=5').index

d1.loc[idx].reset_index()
         Date    BillNo.  Amount
0  10/08/2020  ABBCSQ1ZA     878
1  10/16/2020  AA171E1Z0    5490

d2.loc[idx].reset_index()
         Date    BillNo.  Amount
0  10/08/2020  ABBCSQ1ZA     876
1  10/16/2020  AA171E1Z0    5491
```

---

To make it more generic to work with any *n*.

```
n = 5
idx = (d1-d2).query('Amount>=-@n & Amount<=@n').index
```

**Or**

```
lower_limit = -2 # Example, can be anything
upper_limit = 5  # Example, can be anything
idx = (d1-d2).query('Amount>=@lower_limit & Amount<=@upper_limit').index
```